# How to Identify Export by Name using ImportMany

Tags: c#, wpf, mef, dllimport

I'm trying to ImportMany some exports by name to identify which one I need in some method. I tried:

```
[Export("A",typeof(SomeInIterface.InInterface))]
```

and have ImportMany like

```
[ImportMany(typeof(SomeInInterface.InInterface))]
public Dictionary<string,SomeInInterface.InInterface> in_dict;
```

Interface implementations looks like:

```
public interface InInterface
{
DataSet GetData();
}
```

but after ComposeParts() debugger shows empty `in_dict`

Comment: You need to show more code before we can tell you what your problem is... for example, what type of object is your `ExportAttribute` decorating? Are you sure that you know how to use these attributes correctly? Perhaps the example on the [`ExportAttribute` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.exportattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) page might help?